# Element is disappearing when i use zoomIn animation

Tags: css, animation, zooming

The element is disappearing after css zoomIn animation is finished.
When i remove opacity:0 it will stop vanishing but instead the element appears before the animation (zoomIn) taking place. Why is this happening?

See the behaviour here: https://jsfiddle.net/dhnvwmrs/

```css
@-webkit-keyframes zoomIn {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(0.3, 0.3, 0.3);
    transform: scale3d(0.3, 0.3, 0.3);
  }

  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes zoomIn {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(0.3, 0.3, 0.3);
    transform: scale3d(0.3, 0.3, 0.3);
  }

  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.zoomIn {
  -webkit-animation-name: zoomIn;
  animation-name: zoomIn;
}


#box {
   height:400px;
   width:400px;
   background: red;
   -webkit-animation: zoomIn 2s ease .5s forwards;
   opacity:0;
}
```

```html
<div id="box"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Describe properties for 100%, just copy properties from 50% and it will probably work.

```
    @-webkit-keyframes zoomIn {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(0.3, 0.3, 0.3);
    transform: scale3d(0.3, 0.3, 0.3);
  }

  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }

100% {
        opacity: 1;
      }
}

@keyframes zoomIn {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(0.3, 0.3, 0.3);
    transform: scale3d(0.3, 0.3, 0.3);
  }

  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }

100% {
        opacity: 1;
      }
}

.zoomIn {
  -webkit-animation-name: zoomIn;
  animation-name: zoomIn;
}


#box {
   height:400px;
   width:400px;
   background: red;
   -webkit-animation: zoomIn 2s ease .5s forwards;
   opacity:0;
}
```

Comment: Please accept it as an answer so I can get to higher reputation.

Comment: i have less than 15 reputation..i can`t rate your answer as useful

Comment: Just press "✔" button on the left part. You dont need reputation for that

Answer (score 1):

You should use `to` instead of `50%`:

```css
@-webkit-keyframes zoomIn {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(0.3, 0.3, 0.3);
    transform: scale3d(0.3, 0.3, 0.3);
  }

  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes zoomIn {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(0.3, 0.3, 0.3);
    transform: scale3d(0.3, 0.3, 0.3);
  }

  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.zoomIn {
  -webkit-animation-name: zoomIn;
  animation-name: zoomIn;
}


#box {
   height:400px;
   width:400px;
   background: red;
   -webkit-animation: zoomIn 2s ease .5s forwards;
   opacity:0;
}
```

```html
<div id="box"></div>
```